# Having trouble clamping horizontal camera rotation?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to limit horizontal rotation when colliding with any object but I cannot seem to get it to work using my camera code. I am not using any triggers and the Main Camera is a child of my Player object and I am using standard CharacterController code for my Player Movement script.

To test out the clamping I am just referencing my Player Movement script where I have a simple Raycast casting forward a short distance and a bool isTouchingObj which turns true if the Raycast is hitting a collider. From there I try and use that bool in my camera code to set the x.rotation clamp.

```
// Standard camera for mouse movement
void DoNormalCameraControls()
{
    Vector2 mouseDelta = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis(xAxis), Input.GetAxis(yAxis));

    rotation.x += mouseDelta.x * sensitivity;

    if (rotation.x < 0) rotation.x += 360f;
    if (rotation.x > 360f) rotation.x -= 360f;
    rotation.y += mouseDelta.y * sensitivity;

    rotation.y = Mathf.Clamp(rotation.y, -90f, 90f);

    var xQuat = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotation.x, Vector3.up);
    var yQuat = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotation.y, Vector3.left);

    if (playerMovement.isTouchingObj)
    {
        rotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(rotation.x, -15f, 15f);
        rotation.x = xQuat.eulerAngles.y;
    }

    transform.localRotation = yQuat;
    player.transform.rotation = xQuat;
}
```

```
// Bool condition
public bool isTouchingObj; // reference this bool from inside the Camera script

isTouchingObj = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, 2f);
if (isTouchingObj)
{
}
```

Inside the code above I tried to add an if statement referencing the isTouchingObj bool to set the horizontal clamp but it seems to only work when I turn my camera/mouse to the right. Turning the camera/mouse to the left (beyond the 15f clamp value) causes this weird "snapping" loop to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Need a bit more info as the problem seems a bit specific to you, but I'll try my best - first I recommend simplifying your camera movement like this:

```
[SerializeField] private Transform cam;
void Look() {
    // note: we use GetAxisRaw for a more snappy movement
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X");
    float mouseY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y");
    
    // rotate the object around the Y axis based on the mouse X position
    transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, mouseX * mouseSensitivity, 0);
    // rotate the camera around the X axis based on the mouse Y position
    cam.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(-mouseY * mouseSensitivity, 0, 0);
}
```

Then to fit this to work with yours - you can modify it like this:

```
[SerializeField] private Transform cam;
void Look() {
    // note: we use GetAxisRaw for a more snappy movement
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X");
    float mouseY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y");

    // preconfigure the rotation vars to allow for clamping (i did this just for the x rotation because i only want to clamp looking up and down, you can add the y too if you want that)
    float rotX = Mathf.Clamp(-mouseY * sensitivity, -90, 90);
    // note its negative because looking up and down is inverted
    
    float rotY
    // clamp the Y rotation if we're touching an object
    if (playerMovement.isTouchingObj) {
        rotY = Mathf.Clamp(mouseX * sensitivity, -15, 15)
    }
    else {
        rotY = mouseX * sensitivity;
    
    // rotate the object around the Y axis based on the mouse X position (using rotX instead)
    transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, mouseY * sensitivity, 0);
    // rotate the camera around the X axis based on the mouse Y position
    cam.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(rotX, 0, 0);
}
```

This may not be perfect so please let me know if you have any problems and I'll try my best to help (I hardly ever make 3D games)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, was busy with school work. I can't redo my camera code because I have other code which handles FoV changes, first/third person view, etc and so I'd have to change a lot of code. I tried to integrate your solution into my code but was having no luck. In my exact same script I have another method which clamps x-axis perfectly but it involves Quaternion.RotateTowards and I haven't been able to alter that for my needs here

Comment: i see, the clamp looks like it should work fine, have you checked to see if its a problem with your isTouchingObj bool. Can you send the code for it?

Comment: I added the bool into my main post. I made the condition very simple purely for testing purposes to make sure there was no underlying issue, and I've even tried many other solutions but nothing

Comment: I think I know what to do, but I don't know how to apply it. I am currently trying to get the current rotation while the Raycast is hitting a collider, and then use that rotation as the new rotation (instead of rotation.x) in my clamp. I think that might fix the camera "snap" but I've had no luck